# Why does -d return true on empty variable

Tags: bash

Assume I have not set the environment variable MY_DIR.  Then I do this:

```sh
% if [ -d $MY_DIR ]; then
>  echo WHAT?
> fi
WHAT?
```

I don't get it. Why does -d return TRUE if the environment variable doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without quotes, word-splitting causes the empty string to disappear altogether, and the resulting command is `[ -d ]`. A single non-empty argument (`]` is ignored for the purpose of counting arguments) makes `[` succeed. `[ <word> ]` is interpreted as `[ -n <word> ]`, which tests that `<word>` isn't empty. `[ -d ]` is read as `[ -n -d ]` and always succeeds since `-d` isn't an empty string.

Use quotes.

```
if [ -d "$MY_DIR" ]; then  # when unset, equivalent to [ -d "" ] with two arguments
```

Comment: Hmm.. I thought the quotes around -d as a second argument made a lot of sense :-)

Comment: Whether you use `-d` or `'-d'`, `test` itself sees `-d` as its argument; only the shell uses the quotes, and here the quotes don't actually change how the shell processes the argument.

Comment: Indeed,. To me it just reinforced that `[` sees the `-d` as a word, not a command, but hey ho, I can see both arguments!